# Getting "Request failed with status code 500" error when using Stripe in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

Always getting the same error, when posting the info to the server, it return status 500 error.

This is react code

```
const Pay = () => {

  const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null) 

  const onToken = (token) => {
    setStripeToken(token)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/checkout/payment', {
          tokenId : stripeToken.id,
          amount: 2000,
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    makeRequest()
  }, [stripeToken])

  return (
    <div style={{
      display: "flex", 
      alignItems: "center", 
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100vh"
      }}>
      <StripeCheckout
        name='Afsal shop'
        billingAddress
        shippingAddress
        description='your total is $20'
        amount={2000}
        token={onToken}
        stripeKey={KEY}
      >
        <button style={{
            padding: "10px 20px", 
            background: "black", 
            color: "#fff", 
            cursor: "pointer", 
            borderRadius: "5px",
            fontSize: "25px"
        }}>Pay</button>      
      </StripeCheckout>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the server code, I rechecked with stripe other methods, but stills get same result

```
router.post('/payment', async (req, res) => {
    await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        source: req.body.tokenId,
        amount: req.body.amount,
        currency: "usd",
        automatic_payment_methods: {enabled: true},
    }, (stripeErr, stripeRes) => {
        if(stripeErr){
            return res.status(500).json(stripeErr)
        }else{
            return res.status(200).json(stripeRes)
        }
    })
})
```

I tried different methods but still got the same error again and again (Request failed with status code 500)

Comment: Have you authenticated with the stripe client correctly? Can you pull data from them with a simple request to verify you're connected? I'd also try checking in the stripe dashboard to look at request logs to further debug.

Comment: If your server is returning a 500 response, can you share the content of the Stripe error?  Stripe error message content is generally pretty helpful in debugging.  Also what API version are you using?  I don't see the `source` parameter when I look at the API reference doc for Payment Intents here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create

Answer (score 0):

yes finally, i got a solution from stripe docs(india). Then i changed my code to,

react code

```
const Pay = () => {

  const [stripeToken, setStripeToken] = useState(null) 

  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/checkout/payment', {
          name: "Afsal",
          amount: 10000
        })
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
    makeRequest()
  }, [stripeToken])

  return (
    <div style={{
      display: "flex", 
      alignItems: "center", 
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: "100%",
      height: "100vh"
      }}>
      <StripeCheckout
         name="Afsal Shop"
         image=""
         billingAddress
         shippingAddress
         description="hai"
         amount=10000
         stripeKey={key}
      >
        <button style={{
            padding: "10px 20px", 
            background: "black", 
            color: "#fff", 
            cursor: "pointer", 
            borderRadius: "5px",
            fontSize: "25px"
        }}>Pay</button>      
      </StripeCheckout>
    </div>
  )
}
```

server

```
router.post('/payment', async(req, res) => {
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    description: req.body.name,
    shipping: {
      name: req.body.name,
      address: {
        line1: '510 Townsend St',
        postal_code: '98140',
        city: 'San Francisco',
        state: 'CA',
        country: 'US',
      },
    },
    amount: req.body.amount,
    currency: 'usd',
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
  }, (err, change) => {
    if(err){
      return res.status(500).json(err)
    }else{
      return res.status(200).json(change)
    }
  })
})
```